# Durandal, get path of the current module

Tags: durandal

Is there a way in Durandal to get the path of the current module?   I'm building a dashboard inside of a SPA and would like to organize my widgets in the same way that durandal does with "FolderWidgetName" and the folder would contain a controller.js and view.html file.  I tried using the getView() method in my controller.js file but could never get it to look in the current folder for the view.

```
getView(){  
    return "view"; // looks in the "App" folder  
    return "./view"; // looks in the "App/durandal" folder  
    return "/view"; // looks in the root of the website   
    return "dashboard/widgets/htmlviewer/view" //don't want to hard code the path  
}
```

- I don't want to hardcode the path inside of the controller
- I don't want to override the viewlocator because the rest of the app still functions as a regular durandal spa that uses standard conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `define(['module'], function(module) { ...` in order to get a hold on the current module. `getView()` would than allow you to set a specific view or, like in the example below, dynamically switch between multiple views.

```
define(['module'], function(module) {

  var roles = ['default', 'role1', 'role2'];
  var role = ko.observable('default');
  var modulePath = module.id.substr(0, module.id.lastIndexOf('/') +1);

  var getView = ko.computed(function(){
        var roleViewMap = {
          'default': modulePath + 'index.html',
          role1: modulePath + 'role1.html',
          role2: modulePath + 'role2.html'
        };

        this.role = (role() || 'default');

        return roleViewMap[this.role];
  });


  return {
    showCodeUrl: true,
    roles: roles,
    role: role,
    getView: getView,
    propertyOne: 'This is a databound property from the root context.',
    propertyTwo: 'This property demonstrates that binding contexts flow through composed views.',
    moduleJSON: ko.toJSON(module)
  };


});
```

Here's a live example http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/#/view-composition/getView

Answer (score 0):

Add an **activate** function to your viewmodel as follows:

```
define([],
    function() {
        var vm = {
            //#region Initialization
            activate: activate,
            //#endregion
        };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal methods
    function activate(context) {
        var moduleId = context.routeInfo.moduleId;
        var hash = context.routeInfo.hash;
    }
    //#endregion
});
```

Comment: Any idea how to get the lifecyle events to fire when using a compose binding?  I had this problem before on something else i worked on and asked a question in the google groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/PhNrL6skqtU  but never got an answer

Comment: When you activate a new route deactivate is automatically called on the previous view model, as long as you are exposing it to the router.  That seems to be your question in the google group.

Comment: Chris also you need to return a callback from your activate function which is not clear in the example.

Comment: @kadumel Thanks, I edited to add a full sample viewmodel above. I did not include the router as you did below since the path and moduleId are available without the added dependency.

Comment: You still aren't returning a callback though so the router will stall out in activation.

Comment: @kadumel If you mean I should be returning true or otherwise the router will stop moving through the lifecycle, I haven't included it before and my viewAttached event still fired. That doesn't mean it isn't in the docs, I just haven't seen it and my events still fired. If you mean just including a callback to another internal function, that seems application specific and not necessarily required.

Comment: @kadumel  the problem is getting the lifecycle events when I'm not using a router

Comment: Aaaah makes much more sense now.  Good question.  Have you set up your viewLocator to look in the app folder by default, or into the app/views folder?  http://durandaljs.com/documentation/View-Locator/

Comment: I don't want to change the default configuration of the viewLocator because outside of this page with sub views everything else functions as a standard durandal spa with routing and using the standard conventions

Answer (score 0):

You can simply bind your setup view to router.activeRoute.name or .url and that should do what you are looking for.  If you are trying to write back to the setup viewmodels property when loading you can do that like below.

If you are using the revealing module you need to define the functions and create a module definition list and return it.   Example :

```
define(['durandal/plugins/router', 'view models/setup'],
    function(router, setup) {

var myObservable = ko.observable();

function activate() {
    setup.currentViewName = router.activeRoute.name;
    return refreshData();
}

var refreshData = function () {
    myDataService.getSomeData(myObservable);
};

var viewModel = {
    activate: activate,
    deactivate: deactivate,
    canDeactivate: canDeactivate
};

return viewModel;
});
```

You can also reveal literals, observables and even functions directly while revealing them -

```
    title: ko.observable(true),
    desc: "hey!",
    canDeactivate: function() { if (title) ? true : false,
```

Check out durandal's router page for more info on what is available.  Also, heads up Durandal 2.0 is switching up the router.

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Router/

Comment: The main section of the app uses routing and the lifecycle events works fine for that.  Where im having an issue is basically with sub views and using the compose binding